# How to mapping Entity properties on a "One property -> Many columns" relation

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I'm applying TypeORM with DDD on a Node.JS project with Typescript.

I'm using "transformer" property of "EntitySchema" to map my entity properties to persistence columns. But I can't find the way to do this with one custom type property that must be mapped to two columns instead of one.

This is an example.

This is my model:

```
export default class User {

    public constructor(public id: UuidValueObject, public name: PersonName, public address: Address) {}

}
```

All properties are Value Objects that have 1 property, except "address" that has multiple properties (address, postalCode, etc).

This is my EntitySchema that maps properties to persistence model:

```
export const UserEntity = new EntitySchema<User>({
    name: "User",
    tableName: "users",
    target: User,
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            primary: true,
            transformer: {
                to: (value: UuidValueObject): string => value.id.toString(),
                from: (value: string): UuidValueObject => UuidValueObject.create(value)
            }
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            nullable: true,
            transformer: {
                to: (value: PersonName): any => value.toString(),
                from: (value: any): PersonName => PersonName.create(value)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My question is, how can I add "address" model property to "columns" property of my EntitySchema in the form of multiple distinct columns?

Many thanks.